# tuple() does not change

Tags: python, tuples

I'm having some problem with a tuple. Somehow the variable "verdi" stays as a tuple. I've tried adding `verdi = float(input("text"))` and `verdi = int(input("text"))` but it doesn't change. I read a few threads about the problem, but adding `verdi = int(verdi)` does not seem to work either. It gives the error:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'tuple'

Thats where I am now:

```
  if valg == "1":
    print("some text goes here")
    verdi =  input("SOME TEXT: INT")
    behandler(verdi)

def behandler(*verdi):
  verdi = int(verdi)
  min = input("SOME TEXT: INT")
  maks = input("SOME TEXT: INT")

  for num in min:
    num = min

  for num in maks:
    num = maks

    if verdi > min and verdi < maks:
      -do something-
    else:
      -do something-
```

I get the errors at the `if verdi > min and verdi < maks:`

Any Ideas? :)

Comment: You have a typo in your function definition `def behandler(*verdi):` -- Python will try to pack a sequence here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the asterisk:

```
def behandler(verdi):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`*` is known as the splat operator which packs an arbitrary number of arguments into a tuple, not int.